# Beta regression where fractional response adds up to 100%?

Tags: proportion, beta-regression

I have a data set of people switching brands.
Say #people switching from Brand A to Brand B, C or D.

My data looks like this
`Week   | Brand   | %Switchers | Price
 Week 1 | Brand B | 10%        | 10
 Week 1 | Brand C | 50%        | 8
 Week 1 | Brand D | 40%        | 9`

I have such data for 104 weeks. Note that sum of switcher to Brand B & C & D will always sum to 100. I want to model the influence of `Brand` & `Price` on switching behavior.

Since this is a proportion data, I am applying beta regression model on to it. My equation is

`betareg(%Switchers ~ Brand + Price)`

The model coefficients are significant & model fit is decent. However, the while I predict switching behavior across brands I am finding that `sum(%Switchers)` along `Brand B` `Brand C` `Brand D` are beyond 100% (which doesn't make logical sense).

While I can see where this is coming from (the model doesn't know that `sum(%Switchers)` is `100%` in a given week), I am stumped as to how to interpret such scenarios? Also, is there some other model with will allow me to model proportions *and* limit their sum to `100%` in a given week.

Edit: My problem is not that some `proportions` are `zero` or `one`. It is that `sum of proportions` in a given week are `1`. Hence, IMHO, `zero-one inflated beta regression` doesn't particularly help.

Edit: I don't know why it is marked duplicate of another question. I am specifically mentioning that the linked questions doesn't help answers my key question viz `What if switching probaility across brands come out to be greater than 100%`

Comment: Use the logistic regression if you have # of switchers.

Comment: I do not see how this question is a duplicate of the one indicated.  That one deals with including probabilities of exactly 0 or 1 in a beta regression, this one deals with a Dirichlet-type problem where the estimated probabilities output by a series of beta regressions can and do sum to a number not equal to 1.